# how to sync iTunes 12.5.5 on Ubuntu 16.4?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iphone, itunes

I'm searching answers to sync iTunes 12.5.5 (pictures and musics) on Ubuntu 16.4. 
I have itunes on my iphone 6s.
Which are possibilities that I can try?

Comment: wine do not support drivers so your only solution is to install itunes on a virtual machine and share the usb port with the VM. Thanks to apple and it's close system.

Answer (score 2):

Because Apple doesn't provide iTunes for Ubuntu or Linux in general, you can try to install iTunes using wine or PlayOnLinux. Alternatively you can also create a virtual machine using VirtualBox running Windows and use iTunes in there.

More about how to get iTunes on Ubuntu was discussed on AskUbuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/414737/how-do-i-install-itunes-on-ubuntu